# Extend lifetime of a range for boost::filtered

Tags: c++, boost, range, c++14

I have classes that behave like a lazy container, generating values on the fly.  Then in some cases, I would like to filter the values.  Boost::range::adaptors::filtered seems to be well-suited.  However it does not keep any reference to the "range", it just store the begin/end iterators.

The following code mimics my use case.  But it does not work: the `container` is destroyed before `r` is used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/range/adaptor/filtered.hpp>

#define PING() std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'

using ints = std::vector<int>;

struct container
{
  container() { PING(); }
  ~container() { PING(); }

  using value_type = typename ints::value_type;

  using iterator = typename ints::iterator;
  using const_iterator = typename ints::const_iterator;

  iterator begin() { PING(); return std::begin(c_); }
  iterator end() { PING(); return std::end(c_); }

  const_iterator begin() const { PING(); return std::cbegin(c_); }
  const_iterator end() const { PING(); return std::cend(c_); }

  ints c_ = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
};

int main()
{
  auto r = container{} | boost::adaptors::filtered([](auto&& v) { return v % 2; });
  std::cerr << "Loop\n";
  for (auto i: r)
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

It results in ([live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6a65036b4763ab9)):

```
container::container()
const_iterator container::begin() const
const_iterator container::end() const
const_iterator container::end() const
const_iterator container::end() const
container::~container()
Loop
1
3
5
```

Is there a simple way to ensure that everybody lives as long as I need it?  Of course in `main` I could declare a variable to store the `container{}`, but that's inadequate for my real world use where this container is actually obtained by querying some objects ; I don't want the client side to have to deal with this.

It seems that the simplest would be to rewrite some version of `filtered` that would keep a copy of the range, but I'd like to look for a solution that would avoid writing too much code.  And I'm really looking for a Range-v2 solution: it's probably too soon for me to depend upon Range-v3.

Comment: Are iterators invalidated by a move with your container?  If not, this is easier.

Comment: @Yakk You mean if I move the container to another?  Yes, that would invalidate the iterators.  They are really pointer-like iterators, not indexes.

Comment: Most containers aren't `std::array` like, they are `std::vector` like, in that a `std::move` to another container moves the iterators as well.  And the pointers into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is nasty.

The trick is you have to store the container *first*, then apply the pipe to the stored container, then pretend to be that range-like.

```
template<class X>struct store{ X data; };
template<class Src, class Range>
struct save_src_range:
  private store<Src>,
  Range
{
  // boilerplate for copy/move goes here (TODO)
  template<class S, class RangeFactory>
  save_src_range( S&& s, RangeFactory&& f ):
    store<Src>{std::forward<S>(s)},
    Range( std::forward<RangeFactory>(f)(this->data) )
  {}
};
```

now that needs to be gussed up with a deducing creation function and the like.

Next, we need a syntactically pretty way to insert that capability into the existing syntax.

One approach is like:

```
keep_a_copy( source ) | boost::adapters::filter( ... blah ... )
```

where we do some judo and make it work magically, maybe even after chaining.

Or

```
source | keep_source_copy( boost::adapters::filter( ... blah ... ) )
```

which is a bit easier I think.

I took a stab at it, and it is modestly painful, but I don't see anything fundamentally impossible.  It definitely involves writing too much code.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed ended up with something similar to this.  I hope C++'s Ranges will address such use cases!